# Function query won't execute

Tags: php, mysql, function

Why won't this query work?!?

**Error**

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in E:\xampp\htdocs\pf\shop\buy.php on line 5

**Example Info For Variables**

$character->islots = 20

$chatacter->name = [RE] Tizzle

$e2 = 10

**The Function**

```
function increaseSlots($e2) {
    $slots = ($character->islots)+($e2);
    mysql_query('UPDATE `phaos_characters` SET `inventory_slots`="'.$slots.'" WHERE `name`="'.$character->name.'"'); // <-- Line 5
    if (mysql_affected_rows() != 0) {
        echo 'Inventory Size Incresed By '.$e2.' Slots';
    }else{
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
```

Comment: mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error()); outputs what?

Comment: guess i sued the mysql_error() wrong lol, there is an error there = Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in E:\xampp\htdocs\pf\shop\buy.php on line 5

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong with the syntax though...

Comment: var_dump('UPDATE `phaos_characters` SET `inventory_slots`="'.$slots.'" WHERE `name`="'.$character->name.'"'); dumps what?

Comment: because they don+t exists... is this function increaseSlots() in an class?

Comment: no its not in a class... oh wait it is in a class...

Comment: $character is other object then?? make it global then, function increaseSlots($e2) {  global $character; ....

Comment: sorry, my brain is bleh atm. the $character is defined inside a class in class_character.php

Comment: just put all the need code here. we cannot help you like this...

Comment: yeah im sorry, i just got over being really sick, guess my brain isn't back to 100% yet, I found what i was doing wrong and posted it. I will step back from this project til i am feeling 100% better. lol. obviously i cannot post right either lol.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the docs:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

> > Retrieves the number of rows from a result set. This command is only valid for statements like SELECT or SHOW that return an actual result set. To retrieve the number of rows affected by a INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query, use mysql_affected_rows().

You need to use `mysql_affected_rows()` or better yet, PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Thank you. New I had something else wrong in there too. Now how about the parse error?!?

Answer (score 2):

```
$slots = ($character->islots)+($e2);
```

Looks like there is a typo. Try:

```
$slots = ($character->slots)+($e2);
```

Comment: thats actually my type error on here sorry its supposed to be `$character->islots`

Answer (score 1):

First off you should know that mysql_num_rows only returns a valid result for SELECT or SHOW statements, as stated in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php). You can use [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) for your particular needs.

However, the old PHP MySQL API (that you are using) is being phased out, so I would recommend using mysqli or PDO for your DB connection needs.

While keeping with your requirements, though, you can try to use the following syntax to make sure you receive the MySQL error if it throws one. Your PHP script will stop, but you will see the error.

```
$query = sprintf('UPDATE `phaos_characters` SET `inventory_slots`=%d WHERE `name`="%s"',$slots,$character->name)
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

As a final idea, in situations like this it helps to print out your resulting `$query` and run it manually through something like phpMyAdmin to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Bleh... I Found a better way to do it for the time being.. sorry to waste your guys' time...

I just threw the $character object into a variable before processing the function.

```
function increaseSlots($e2,$charname,$charslots) {
    $slots = $charslots+$e2;
    mysql_query('UPDATE `phaos_characters` SET `inventory_slots`="'.$slots.'" WHERE `name`="'.$charname.'"');
        if (mysql_affected_rows() != 0) {
            echo 'Inventory Size Incresed By '.$e2.' Slots';
        }
}
```